# How many workflow in progress can a document library handle?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, archive

I have a task where when an item is added on a document library, there will be a retention of the item. After 1 year it will be delete on that document library and then transfer to a different document library which is an archive document library.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question, you are trying to do what the SharePoint retention policy settings do with a workflow. Did you try setting up retention policy for your document library? [Article on how to do is here](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint)

Also, I wouldn't recommend workflow instances running for a year on your document library. Either set up some external archiving Powershell script as scheduled task to move documents out or set up retention policy.

Comment: Hi @Arvi thanks for the answer! will look in to this.

Comment: The link that you provided does't seem to work.

Comment: Fixed link now.

Comment: Upon checking retention policy of SharePoint, it only moves the item to Recycle bin or permanently delete the item. Is there a way where i can move it to another document library? My last idea is to make an console job that run daily to check if the document is a year old.

Comment: @silentgut, you may use a powershell script instead of a console app. Or write your own custom timer job (c#) for SP farm.

Comment: What SP-Version are you using? You should also have the option to move the item around... https://imgur.com/tzEAX4Q - The only thing you need to consider is that the timer job is not running often (weekly only)

Comment: @HeikoHatzfeld_MSFT I'm using SharePoint 2010. I cannot use the option "Transfer to another location" because that will transfer the document to a different site collection. My goal is to transfer it to a different document library with the same site collection.

Comment: @AlexZh Yes I think i have no choice to create a powershell script for this matter. Thanks for the advice!